# ArgoCD CLI SSO login not working : PermissionDenied desc = Forbidden

Tags: single-sign-on, argocd

Currently I have an sso login associated with ArgoCD and trying to have CLI access to ArgoCD.

but when I run

```
argocd login argo.domain.com --sso
```

Getting error

```
FATA[0001] rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = Forbidden
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: you need a LOT more info than this; for example is OIDC/SAML correctly configured? can you validate this from the UI? Are there any logs in `argocd-server` that give more insight?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever SSO you got set up doesn't support the PKCE flow. ArgoCD web UI uses the usual "webapp" flow as it has the client id and the client secret. ArgoCD CLI can use either the PKCE or the implicit flows (neither of which supports the client secret).

Make sure your OIDC provider is configured as appropriate.